# How do I define a variable that all my views can access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, helpermethods

I have a Rails 5 web app (almost).  I want to include an attribute on all my views.  I read somewhere that the way to do this was to define a helper method in my application controller, so I defined

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :store_last_page_visited

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  helper_method :unvoted_people
    ...

    def unvoted_people
      @unvoted_people = People.find_most_voted(current_user)
    end
```

I only have an application layout for all my pages, yet in my view the logic after

```
<% if @unvoted_people %>
```

never gets called, even though I know the query should return results.  What's the right way to include a model attribute that all my views can access?

Answer (score 1):

you should be calling `unvoted_people` the helper method you defined in the application_controller, you can get rid of the instance variable and return it from the `unvoted_people` method.

Comment: Ok that seems to work.  But I have a follow up question.  Right after my "<% if unvoted_people %>" line, I have a "<% unvoted_people.each do |person| %>" line taht iterates over the results.  Am I repeatedly calling the method?  How do I only invoke the method once and use its result multiple times?

Comment: `@unvoted_people ||= People.find_most_voted(current_user)`

Comment: @Natalia yes you can use Brad's suggestion to cache those results so you don't end hitting the database on every call of the method

Comment: Thanks and just so I'm clear, where does the "@unvoted_people ||= People.find_most_voted(current_user)" line belong, is that the body of my helper method?

Comment: @Natalia Yes exactly